# PostgreSQL & PgAdmin set session variable to query result

Tags: postgresql

Why am I getting this error?

```
set session my.vars.id = SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "ID" = 1;
SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = current_setting('my.vars.id');
...
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 1: set session my.vars.id = SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "...
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can only use constants in a `SET` command.

Try this:

```
SELECT set_config('my.vars.id', "Name", FALSE)
FROM "Client" WHERE "ID" = 1;
```

Comment: I am trying to set a variable equal to a query's response. I then want to use that variable in many different querys. Would you mind showing me how your answer helps with this? Sorry I just don't know what set_config does

Comment: `SELECT set_config('var1', (SELECT "Name" FROM "Client" WHERE "ID" = 1), TRUE);
SELECT * FROM "Client" WHERE "Name" = current_setting('var1');`

Is this corrent? What does the `TRUE` do?

Comment: It does exactly what you want - set `my.vars.id` to the result of your query. Please read [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) for details. `TRUE` changes the value only for the duration of the current transaction.

Comment: When you say `..value only for the duration of the current transaction` do you mean transaction = script? The value is changed for the current script?

Comment: No, I mean a [database transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). Did you try my answer? Does it work as you want?

Comment: Yes but the comment I added is how it solved my issue. Maybe just copy my comment into your answer?...is it bad practice to store variables here? Does it not clog up your system every time you save a new variable?

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. No, the old one is just overwritten.